# Apache site only accessible on local environment

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, apache-2.2

I'm running Apache HTTP Server 2.2 on a Windows 2008 box. But for some reason, I can only get the site to load locally.

The box is assigned 3 IP addresses. I already configured IIS to listen to the first 2 IPs and assigned Apache the third by specifying 'Listen 209.67.xxx.xx:80' in the httpd.conf file. I think it was a pretty standard installation and that is the only thing I changed.

I then bring up the browser in server and type in the IP. The default page with "It works!" appears. Great! But when I try to hit that page from another machine from outside, it takes a few seconds and then just loads an empty page. Nothing in the page html source either.

I know it's not a firewall issue because IIS is able to serve up pages all day. It's not something with that IP because when I tell IIS to listen to that IP, it works.

One other odd thing, when I 'telnet 209.67.xxx.xx 80' it seems to connect fine. Then I do a 'get' and it's the same thing as the browser...thinks for a few seconds, then returns nothing.

I've gotten this setup to work in another environment a few weeks ago but we migrated to a new data center and now it's not working. Not sure what else to do here. Is it an Apache configuration I'm missing? Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `LogLevel debug` and look what is happening in access and error logs. Note, that VirtualHOsts may have their own LogLevel settings - change them too.

Try to completely disable firewall for testing: IIS is working OK, but firewall may have special rules for different programs.

Copy apache with all configs to win2003/winxp machine and look, if it works there. You will see, if this bug is in apache configuration or somewhere in OS settings.

Comment: Well I feel silly. Indeed it was the Windows firewall that was blocking it. I checked the network firewall but didn't have the sense to check the local firewall. I added Apache to the list of allowed programs and now it's running just fine. Thanks.